# Why isn't this working? I'm not getting the expected output

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a simple program using a method to calculate age from user input. But when the code is ran I get the text but no integer result for Age.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace csharpExercises
{
    class Program
    {            
        public static int calcAge (int yourAge) {
            int currentYear;
            int year = 2016;
            currentYear = year - yourAge;
            return currentYear;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the year you were born in: ");
            int Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            calcAge(Age);
            Console.WriteLine("Your age is : ", Age);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to comments OP already solved the issue

Answer (score 7):

The method `calcAge` is calling correctly with an integer value, and it will return an integer as well.

Two things you have to notice:

1. You don't receive/Displaying the integer value returning from that calling method.
2. The display statement that you are using is not well-formatted, you forgot/have not specified the placeholder for displaying the value. or else you have to use a `+` for concatenate the output.

Call the method like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age is :{0}", calcAge(Age));
```

or like this :

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age is :" + calcAge(Age));
```

or like this;

```
int currentAge=calcAge(Age);
Console.WriteLine("Your age is :{0}", currentAge)
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Your age is : ", + calcAge(Age)); and I'm still getting an output with no value.

Comment: Ok this worked thanks alot   Console.WriteLine("Your age is :{0}",  calcAge(Age));

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Your age is :" + calcAge(Age));` will also work, you have an additional comma there before `+` please remove that